# Redirect IP & Dynu to real domain and remove trailing slash

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect my IP address and my Dynu domain to my actual domain.

**This currently works:**

```
# Rewrite Rules
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^muffy.northernia.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://muffy.northernia.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

1) The user tries to access my public IP (155.4.32.16) they get redirected to muffy.northernia.com.

2) The user tries to access my Dynu domain (e191374.dynu.net) they get redirected to muffy.northernia.com.

**Now the problem begins:**

When the user get redirected, Apache adds two slashes and I can't remove them.
Example: I access 155.4.32.16/admin/nologon and it redirects me to muffy.northernia.com//admin/nologon. Notice the two slashes.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//+(.*)$
RewriteRule / http://muffy.northernia.com/%1/%2 [R=301,L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.
by default "$1" contains the index path "/".

Changed:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://muffy.northernia.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

To:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://muffy.northernia.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

The API wrapper for dynu I wrote could be useful to you: https://github.com/adm-github/godynu